# Problems with lookup connection in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oracle10g

I am trying to use a Lookup task in SSIS. The source is a table in a SQL server, and the lookup table belongs to an Oracle Database.

until now I've got the next schema:

[image]

As you can see, I have not problems by wathching the preview of the lookup table, but when I try to execute the task I'm getting ONLY this error message:

```
[Lookup [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "OLEDB STBY" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
```

Until now I have no found a solution for this.

As a provider I am using the Native OLEDB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle, but I have used the Oracle Provider for OLE DB with the same result.

Regards.

Comment: Check that your package's execution bit mode matches your Oracle drivers (32 or 64 bit)

Comment: Also, `There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed`

Comment: Please post all the error messages that you received before and after the one you posted.

Comment: That is the only message I've got. Nothing else, that is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. After several tests I proved by changing the ProtectionLevel of the packet and the project and now I can FINALLY download data from my Oracle source.